# Which will be best method for awakening 7 Chakras?

Tags: chakras

As I am very eager to know about Chakras & awakening them for well being.

I have read a lot about them but they all are refer to different methods like do some yogas or chanting matras etc.

Does any have solid reference about it from our ancient books ?

You can find reference that science even also agreeing with chakras.
https://gostica.com/aura-science/proof-energy-chakras-confirmed-science-finally-proves-meridians-exist/
https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-scientific-proof-of-the-existence-of-chakras

Comment: Only an accomplished Guru in that field can explain this question. @MKP

Comment: But does any ancient book referring it ?

Comment: Theory will be explained by many,  which will be of no use,  unless practised under a competent accompanied Guru @MKP

Comment: @Wikash_ If you dont believe event 1% in hinduism, you can please quit the site and go to a subject which interests you. Stop posting such comments again and again.

Comment: Awakening of chakras is not a cakewalk as todays science suggests. Today science knows only basic 7 chakras . But they are not in your physical body. There's a key to enter Mooladhara. Only a accompolished YOGI/Guru knows. Learn that knowledge from Indian traditional sages written experience!

Comment: @Wikash_ don't post atheistic comments on the site. If you don't believe in Hinduism beliefs and philosophy, you should ignore the QA instead of posting irrelevant and non; constructive comments